# Make a sub-folder based on a start and stop number range and an ID number

Tags: php

I am working with a system that has ID numbers that are 9 digits long and look like this.... **100001000** The last 4 digits are mainly what I will have to work with.

Using PHP I have an Image uploader to upload product related images which then have the ID number within the filename.

To avoid having hundreds of thousands of images in a single folder I would like to store images into subfolders based on a range of numbers.

So for example 500 ID related images max per folder and the ID is **100001000** so any image with an ID between **100001000** and **100001500** will go to folder 100001000, **100002000** and **100002500** will go to folder 100002000, **100003000** and **100003500** will go to folder 100003000, etc...

The reason that I need to do it in this manner is because there is no database in use on this single page project.   So not only does it need to organize the images into subfolders like this but also done in this manner so that  the proper images can in the future be retrieved just by knowing the ID number I can then easily determine the subfolder it belongs to.

I  know this should be a simple math equation but I am not sure the best way to do a simple function to determine the folder based on the ID number?

I would like to be able to pass in the ID number into a PHP function and have it spit out the correct Folder number for that ID....

```
function getFolder($idNumber){
    retunr $folderNumber;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following equations are based on the assumption that the last 4 numbers will always be between 1000 and 9999:

```
x: the last 4 numbers
folderNr: floor[ (x - 1000) / 500 ]
folderName: 100000000 + (1000 + 500 * folderNr)
```

Examples:

```
x: 1200
folderNr: floor[ 0,4 ] = 0
folderName: 100000000 + 1000 = 100001000

x: 2500
folderNr: floor[ 3 ] = 3
folderName: 100000000 + 2500 = 100002500
```